# Magento copy Regular price into special price

Tags: magento-1.9

I need any script to copy all Regular price into special price. My condition is if `my_attribute = 10` then copy all Regular price into special price

is any query available. If it's there please suggest me otherwise suggest me some easy way because i have `1500+` product is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,

1. **you need to call catalog product Collection by**
   `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')`.
2. Then  `filter the collection by my_attribute = 10` using

*`addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute',array('eq'=>10))`*

3. and select ***special_price,price, special_to_date,special_from_date***
   using  `addAttributeToSelect('attribute_code')`
4. Then using `getResource()->saveAttribute()`  quick *update the special*
   price

### Script:

---

> ```
> require_once 'Your_Magento_Dir/app/Mage.php';
> umask(0);
> Mage::app("admin");
>
> // call product collection.
>
> $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
>
> /* *FIlter the collectin by  my_attribute = 10 */
>
> $collection->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute',array('eq'=>10));
>
>  /* special_price,price, special_to_date,special_from_date  */
>
> $collection
>   ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
>   ->addAttributeToSelect('special_pirce')
>   ->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date')
>   ->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date');
>
>
> /* Using loop update  and getResource()->saveAttribute() */
>
> foreach($collection as $product){
>     $Price=$product->getPrice();
>     $product->setSpecialPrice($Price);
>
>     $product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
>     $product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
>     $product->setSpecialToDate('End_Date'); // YYYY-MM-DD
>     $product->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true);
>    /* quick save */
>     $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_price');
>     $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');
>
>     $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_to_date');
>
>
> }
> ```

**Note: I will be  better to run the script using shell command**

Comment: Can i use in this way in category id